# Html Link in pop up button

Tags: html

I want to add a link in the text of one popup info button.

This is the code

```
<a class="icon-tooltip" data-container="body" data-content="you can find more information" data-html="true" data-original-title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" role="button" tabindex="0" title=""><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-icon_info"></span></a>
```

In the `data-content="you can find more information"` I want more information to be with a link to another site.

How can I do that?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please share more details - what kind of "popup info button" are you talking about? Is there any JS module involved that renders this popup?

Answer (score 0):

If the tooltip is generated by a library which supports HTML in tooltips (and based on `data-html="true"` it does) then all you would need should be the following:

```
data-content="You can find <a href='example.com'>more information</a>"
```

Pay attention to the different quotation marks used in the `<a>` Tag in the property.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works. I tried that before but with "" and not with ''

Comment: If it answers your question, please think about marking this as solved.